# quill - can't tokenize a non-scalar lifting

Tags: scala, quill.io

I'm currently getting this error and I can't quite figure out why:

`exception during macro expansion: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't tokenize a non-scalar lifting. AgentService.this.agentsByOrganization(id).id`

Do I need to convert the Ids to `Long` prior to making the query? I'd like to be able to use the specific Id class, but I'm new to Scala and not sure if that is possible. In addition, not all of the queries fail. For example, `delete` works, even though it is also being passed an `AgentId`. Whereas the `findByOrganization` method does not work. Other methods that are passed an `AgentId` are also showing the same errors as `findByOrganization`.

model:

```
case class AgentId(value: Long) extends AnyVal
case class OrganizationId(value: Long) extends AnyVal
case class Agent(
                  id: AgentId
                  , identifier: String
                  , organizationId: OrganizationId
                  , createdAt: LocalDateTime
                  , updatedAt: LocalDateTime
                )
```

service:

```
class AgentService(implicit val ex: ExecutionContext, val ctx: DBContext)
  extends AgentsRepository {
  import ctx._

  def listByOrganization(id: OrganizationId): List[Agent] =
    ctx.run(agentsByOrganization(id)) // this returns the error

  def delete(agent: RichAgent): Unit = {
    ctx.run(deleteAgent(agent)) // this doesn't
  }
}
```

repository:

```
trait AgentsRepository extends Repository {
  import ctx._

  def agentsByOrganization(id: OrganizationId) = quote { // error
    query[Agent].filter(_.organizationId == lift(id))
  }

  def agentById(id: AgentId) = quote {
    query[Agent].filter(_.id == lift(id))
  }

  def deleteAgent(agent: Agent) = quote { agentById(agent.id).delete }
}
```

db

```
import io.getquill.{PostgresJdbcContext, SnakeCase}

package object db {
  class DBContext(config: String) extends PostgresJdbcContext(SnakeCase, config)

  trait Repository {
    val ctx: DBContext
  }
}
```

I've seen this [similar issue](https://github.com/getquill/quill/issues/584), but it seems specific to `Option`. Here's a [scastie snippet](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jmkoni/uyRY2u9JQxGwKaBc7CgZOg).

Comment: Could you also specify how your `DBContext` and most importantly `ctx` (the one that is used in `import ctx._`) are defined? Your code seems to compile for me if I use `val ctx = new H2JdbcContext(SnakeCase, "ctx")`

Comment: @SergGr added the `DBContext`.

Comment: Is that true that your code fails to compile? Your scastie snippet fails much earlier so it is not a [MCVE]. And if I try to extend it in my local environment, it seems to compile for me. I'm using `"io.getquill" %% "quill-jdbc" % "2.3.1"`. Not sure where else there might be a difference.

Comment: It did fail to compile and somewhere while I was making other changes it finally compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what happened, but now it is working:

```
    case class AgentId(value: Long) extends AnyVal
case class Agent(
                  id: AgentId
                  , identifier: String
                  , organizationId: OrganizationId
                  , createdAt: LocalDateTime
                  , updatedAt: LocalDateTime
                )
case class RichAgent(
                  id: AgentId
                  , identifier: String
                  , organization: Organization
                )
```

service

```
class AgentService(implicit val ex: ExecutionContext, val ctx: DBContext)
  extends AgentsRepository {
  import ctx._

  def listByOrganization(id: OrganizationId): List[Agent] =
    ctx.run(agentsByOrganization(id))

  def delete(agent: Agent): AgentId = {
    AgentId(ctx.run(deleteAgent(agent.id)))
  }
}
```

repository

```
trait AgentsRepository extends Repository {
  import ctx._

  val agents = quote {
    query[Agent]
  }

  def agentsByOrganization(id: OrganizationId) = quote {
    agents.filter(_.organizationId == lift(id))
  }

  def agentById(id: AgentId) = quote {
    agents.filter(_.id == lift(id))
  }

  def deleteAgent(agentId: AgentId) = quote { agentById(agentId).delete }
}
```

db

```
object db {
  class DBContext(config: String) extends PostgresJdbcContext(SnakeCase, config)

  trait Repository {
    val ctx: DBContext
  }
}
```